# Get current date in this format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, formatting

How can I get the current date in Javascript and format it this way "2015-03-25T12:00:00" ?

I would like to know if there is a function or method for this. I am not asking how to convert a string into another.

Comment: `Date.toISOString()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: You have to be careful with Date.toISOString() though...it's not supported by older browsers like IE8.

Comment: Also, toISOString is UTC by default, the OP seems to want sans timezone (so local).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I get the current date in Javascript and format it this way "2015-03-25T12:00:00" ?

That seems to be an ISO 8601 format date without a timezone, which will be treated as a "local" time. There is a built—in [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) method, but it always uses UTC.

So you can either write your own function (fairly trivial, see below) or use a library (really not required if you just want to format a date string).

> I would like to know if there is a function or method for this.

Not a built–in function, no.

```js
/* Return an ISO 8601 string without timezone
** @param {Date} d - date to create string for
** @returns {string} string formatted as ISO 8601 without timezone
*/
function toISOStringLocal(d) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
         z(d.getDate()) + 'T' + z(d.getHours()) + ':' +
         z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getSeconds())
          
}

document.write(toISOStringLocal(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 8):

To be precise: `.toISOString().slice(0, -5)`

```js
var d1 = new Date()
var str = d1.toISOString().slice(0, -5)
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use moment.js It will blow your mind. Add this script to you HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

And use this code:

```
var date=moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function(d) {

    var cad = "";

    try{
              cad =  d.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + pad(d.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + pad(d.getUTCDate()) + "T" + pad(d.getHours()) 
              + ":" + pad(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + pad( d.getSeconds()) ;  

      return cad;
    }catch(e){
      return null;
    }  

  }
```